# How to create a database that updates by connecting to an online server - Android

Tags: android, sql-server, database, database-design, webserver

I am trying to make an announcement app for an organization. I am using a listview to display the announcements in an activity. I have the listview set up, each item in the list will have a Title, and a Subtitle (describing the announcement). When the user clicks on an announcement, they are taken to a new activity with the title at the top and the information in paragraphs under it.

However, I want the app to update weekly by accessing an online database containing the list of announcements (I have a domain so maybe I can host it under my own IP address). The idea is that the app will update on a weekly basis and update the device's storage with the new announcements (so users can view it offline).

I have no idea where to start. This is my first android app, I am a beginner - but I have intermediate experience in Java. I also have lots of experience with Excel, and SQL through MS Access. I just don't know how to put it into Java to create an online database for android.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

That might not be exactly what you need but [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql) has some great information on how to connect an android app to an external database. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an Android Service with AlarmManager. You can code your Service to wake after every 7 days and then fetch the data from your database.
But kindly check the amount of resources you would be using or wasting.

Refer AlarmManager : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
Refer Service : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html